# How do I pass Mocha multiple files by path on the command line?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am amassing a list of test files which need to be run.  I'd like to pass them into Mocha via the command line.  My current command looks like this:

```
{here}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -u tdd --timeout 999999 --colors --file {here}/tests/core/core_tests.js -R json > {here}/rpt.json
```

The spec for mocha says I should be able to repeat that --file  pattern infinitely to load multiple files, but when I do this with even one I get this error:

```
Warning: Cannot find any files matching pattern "test"
```

This core_tests.js file, when run directly without the --file option, runs just fine.

What am I missing?  How do I pass multiple files without doing it by directory?